# Select a random XPath element

Tags: c#, selenium

Hy,
on a website there are some button:

*Previously I copied the old code to the question, this is the actual code:*

```
IWebElement btn_tag_1 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@data-testid ='tag_eject']"));
IWebElement btn_tag_2 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@data-testid ='tag_close']"));
IWebElement btn_tag_3 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@data-testid ='tag_open']"));
IWebElement btn_tag_4 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@data-testid ='tag_selected']"));
IWebElement btn_tag_5 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@data-testid ='tag_disabled']"));
IWebElement btn_tag_6 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@data-testid ='tag_free']"));
```

In a normal case when I would like to click a selected element for example "btn_tag_1" the code is:

```
btn_tag_1.Click();
```

But now I wanted to click one of them selected randomly and I'm totally stucked at this point.
Can You help me in this case?
Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just looking for some help on how to randomly click one of the buttons then I would do it this way:

```
using System;
using OpenQA.Selenium;    

By[] buttonsBy = {
     By.XPath("//*[@data-testid='tag_1']"),
     By.XPath("//*[@data-testid='tag_2']"),
     By.XPath("//*[@data-testid='tag_3']"),
     By.XPath("//*[@data-testid='tag_4']"),
     By.XPath("//*[@data-testid='tag_5']"),
     By.XPath("//*[@data-testid='tag_6']")
};

int index = new Random().Next(buttonsBy.Length - 1);

IWebElement button = driver.FindElement(buttonsBy[index]);

button.Click();
```

Create an array with your By selectors, choose a random number within the length of that array, find the element using that random number as the index and then click.

Added after comment with code:

All you need to do is change the string inside each locator to use the code in your comment.

```
By[] buttonsBy = {
     By.XPath("//*[@data-testid='tag_eject']"),
     By.XPath("//*[@data-testid='tag_close']"),
     By.XPath("//*[@data-testid='tag_open']"),
     By.XPath("//*[@data-testid='tag_selected']"),
     By.XPath("//*[@data-testid='tag_disabled']"),
     By.XPath("//*[@data-testid='tag_free']")
};
```

Comment: Hy,
Your solution seems to be good but i made a huge mistake in the question, I copied an old code....

Comment: So my code right now:


`IWebElement btn_tag_1 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@data-testid ='tag_eject']"));
IWebElement btn_tag_2 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@data-testid ='tag_close']"));
IWebElement btn_tag_3 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@data-testid ='tag_open']"));
IWebElement btn_tag_4 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@data-testid ='tag_selected']"));
IWebElement btn_tag_5 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@data-testid ='tag_disabled']"));
IWebElement btn_tag_6 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@data-testid ='tag_free']"));`

Comment: The only difference with your update is the string used for your XPath locator.  In my example, you just need to make that change in the array.  I'll add to my answer to show it.